# Tab closed on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to get the tabs on this page to be closed on page load. http://krankgolf2017.wpengine.com/champions/

I'm pretty sure bootstrap is being used for the tabs. I've tried what it says on this bootstrap page but nothing seems to work: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

I did try add "collapse" to this div. It works but then when clicked it does not open.

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab-1490189985481-0-4" class="tab-pane active">
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid collapse">...</div>
</div>
<div id="tab-1490189985481-0-5" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="tab-1490189985742-0-6" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="tab-1490189985901-0-4" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="tab-1490189986038-0-10" class="tab-pane">...</div>
</div>
```

I have reached out to the theme developer and they could not help me.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: can you try removing the active class from tab-pane active? <div id="tab-1490189985481-0-4" class="tab-pane active"> to <div id="tab-1490189985481-0-4" class="tab-pane">

Comment: You are using tabs not collapsable, so adding the class will not help. Anyway, does it make any sense to use tabs, when you want to hide the content?

Comment: Not sure, I am trying to do something like this page:
http://www.callawaygolf.com/team-callaway/

Answer (score 0):

@mrsq is correct. Removing *active* will do the trick for the div tab-pane, but you also need to remove *class='active'* from the li tag around customer support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I understand and agree. The only problem is that class is part of Visual Composer > inserting the theme's tabs. So I'm not quite sure where to change that. Again the theme developer will not help me on this one.